# UIPrintInteractionController crashes on presentation

Tags: swift, crash, breakpoints, interaction

When presented in a standalone single view application the following code works a treat.

When pasted into an app running on an iPad (with splitview controller) and initiated from a UIAlertController action off a button, it crashes (triggers a breakpoint at the top of the AppDelegate - Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2) as soon as the print interaction sheet appears. I've even tried firing it up from within a dedicated UIViewController with no luck. Any ideas?

```
    let pInfo = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
    pInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
    pInfo.jobName = "Shopping List"
    pInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientation.portrait

    let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: "<html><body>Hellow world!</body></html>")

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printController.printInfo = pInfo
    printController.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true
    printController.printFormatter = formatter
    printController.delegate = self
    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```